# Integer() type cast doesn't work on Delphi 64-bit

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, integer, delphi-xe2, typecast-operator

I have the following piece of code:

```
inc(integer(DestPixel), DestDelta); //DestPixel: PColorRGB; DestDelta: integer;
```

This works fine on 32-bit platforms. If I change the platform to 64-bit in the compiler the compiler emits this error:

> E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to

The problem seems to be in the `integer()` typecast. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Is this line of code from JanFx.Stretch function? You will have to use INT_PTR or NativeInt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the 64 bit platform, `DestPixel` is 8 bytes wide, `Integer` is 4 bytes and so the typecast is invalid. You can fix this problem by using [`NativeInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.NativeInt) instead.

```
inc(NativeInt(DestPixel), DestDelta);
```

The `NativeInt` type is the same size as a pointer and so floats between 4 bytes and 8 bytes wide depending on the output target.

Having said that, I personally would typecast with `PByte` because that more correctly describes the operation you are performing.

```
inc(PByte(DestPixel), DestDelta);
```

Comment: +1 for using PByte which indicates that you are working with pointers and not "integer values".

Comment: @Andreas, but wouldn't be more natural to use typecast to `PColorRGB` ? I mean `Inc(PColorRGB(DestPixel), DestDelta);`

Comment: @tlama that would have a different meaning if TColorRGB has size greater than 1

Comment: When using pointer arithmetic, you can omit the second parameter of `Inc()` when advancing one item as a time. The compiler will determine the correct number of bytes to advance.